# Search function (using dropdownlist) in asp.net and vb.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a simple or example code where i can display a table/gridview when using a dropdownlist as search function (in asp.net with vb.net). I already created a table in the sql database (and have information in it).

i just need search the value in the dropdownlist and when click the btnsearch, it will load the table.

```
    Private Sub LoadGridTbale(Optional sortExpression As String = "")

        Dim dt As DataSet

        dt = db.ExecuteSelect("SELECT StaffId, convert(varchar,dob,103) as dob, staff_name, staff_address," & _
                        " mobile_no, department_no" & _
                        "FROM emp_staff ")
'i want to write the code here
```

I could not find any example search for it on asp.net with vb.net

update

```
        dt = db.ExecuteSelect("SELECT staffId, convert(varchar,dob,103) as dob, staff_name, staff_address," & _
                        " mobile_no, department_no" & _
                        "FROM emp_staff WHERE staffId='" & txtid.Text & "' OR dob='" & dob.text & "' OR staff_name='" & staff_name.SelectedValue & "' OR staff_address='" & add.text & "' ")
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of what you expect `sortExpression` to be?

Comment: basically to sort the table asc or desc

Comment: <code>If sortExpression = "" Then
                rs = db.ExecuteSelect(querystring, Session("CnnStr").ToString)
            Else
                rs = db.ExecuteSelect(querystring & " ORDER BY " & sortExpression, Session("CnnStr").ToString)
            End If <code>

Comment: i already figure it out